# bad JAVA_HOME or missing support for your architecture?

Tags: java, mesos, mesosphere

The following error appeared while installing Apache mesos can you please help me

```
configure: error: failed to determine linker flags for using Java (bad JAVA_HOME or missing support for your architecture?)

file:///home/ccompl06-14/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202015-05-28%2009:24:42.png
```

Comment: You need to install Java.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: This should help you in setting JAVA_HOME   http://www.javavirtues.com/2012/12/setting-up-java-development-environment.html

Comment: I get this error even with Java installed:
```configure: using JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64
configure: error: failed to determine linker flags for using Java (bad JAVA_HOME or missing support for your architecture?)```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to set JAVA_HOME on Unix and Linux:

1. export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk_1.6
2. export $PATH= ${PATH}:{JAVA_HOME}/bin

For more details refer

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/how-to-set-javahome-environment-in.html

Comment: You are missing a dollar sign at JAVA_HOME in PATH. should be export PATH= ${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you do not have a JDK installed on your system.  Have a look at [this site which answers your question](http://jugnu-life.blogspot.com/2013/08/building-mesos-from-source.html):

```
Download JDK
set env variable as
export JAVA_HOME=C:/path/to/your/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply  i am working in Linux environment and i have installed JDK too

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: [link] http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/  using this i am trying to install apache mesos but while ../configure step i got above mention error of bad java home